# VapourSynth Editor - Failed to load vapoursynth script library!

Tags: libraries

I have installed VapourSynth Editor on lubuntu 16.04, but when I open the program with the following script:

> import vapoursynth as vs 
>   core = vs.get_core() 
>   video = core.ffms2.Source(source='video.mp4') 
>   video.set_output()

I get this error:

> 2017-06-05 23:50:15.334 
>   Failed to load vapoursynth script library! 
>   Please set up the library search paths in settings. 
>   Failed to load vapoursynth script library! 
>   Please set up the library search paths in settings. 
>   Failed to load vapoursynth script library! 
>   Please set up the library search paths in settings. 
>   Failed to load vapoursynth script library! 
>   Please set up the library search paths in settings. 
>   Failed to load vapoursynth script library! 
>   Please set up the library search paths in settings.

I know nothing about Linux. What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You might have not installed VapourSynth itself or done it wrong.
Try using this manual:
http://www.l33tmeatwad.com/vapoursynth101/software-setup

Comment: It gives me an error when I try to compile Cython: src/cython/vapoursynth.pyx:574:15: Expected ')', found 'f' - Makefile:2011: recipe for target 'src/cython/vapoursynth.c' failed - make: *** [src/cython/vapoursynth.c] Error 1